# WPF , ObservableCollections, bindings and stuff . When i iterably try to remove the whole collection I'm only capable of removing only it's half

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've came to WPF from winforms , and I'm prety new to it . So here is my question . When i iterably try to remove items from ObservableCollection binded to ListBox via lambda expression it works just fine :

```
ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.ToList().All(i => ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.Remove(i));
```

But when i try using this method , i'am only capable of removing only half of items for each time this code runs :

```
for (int i = 0; i < ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.Count.ToString() + " " + i.ToString());
        ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.RemoveAt(i);
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp)));

}
```

1 The first question is why .
2 The second question is if this question is stupid ?
3 The third question is , how to get a grip on WPF and understand how to work with it if the question is stupid

Comment: By the time your count gets past half, half of the collection will also be removed so there will be no items on those index's. When removing items from a collection in a for loop you should loop backwards :) (or use the solution from the answer that works fine as well)

Answer (score 0):

You should not advance i after item i is removed, e.g.

```
while (ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.Any())
{
    ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Also, there is no need to raise the PropertyChanged event. ObservableCollection raises CollectioNChanges events automatically whenever someting is added or removed.

Comment: ooooh , i get it now . I missed the feature of this data type . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

deleting items from ObservableCollection one-by-one is extrimely unefficient. It will cause N collection change notifications and UI updates, where N is the original size of collection.

any `Collection<T>` has `Clear()` method.

make it simply

```
ObservableCollectionGoodsListBoxTemp.Clear();
```